# NoSuchMethodError when compiling in Eclipse with Spring IDE

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-ide

I have a development environment based on Eclipse Juno with Spring IDE installed. My project uses also Spring Security. The Spring version I am using is 2.5.5 and Spring Security is at 2.0.6. Now, after updating Spring IDE from 3.1.0 to 3.3.0, I am getting a NoSuchMethodError when Spring compiler is trying to compile this line:

```
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.mycompany.security.MyUserDetailsService">
    <property name="daoFactory" ref="DaoFactory" />
</bean>
```

MyUserDetailsService implements `UserDetailsService` and `InitializingBean`.

schemaLocation for the file has been defined as:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.6.xsd"
```

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
!MESSAGE Error occured processing '/Server/WEB-INF/business-layer-context.xml'
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.addConstructorArg(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
at org.springframework.security.config.AuthenticationProviderBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AuthenticationProviderBeanDefinitionParser.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1400)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1330)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:494)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:402)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:388)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:445)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
```

When compiling the application with Ant script and starting the server, everything works fine, so the problem is limited to Eclipse and Spring IDE. Both my Ant and Eclipse configurations use the same Spring library. `addConstructorArg` method still seems to exist in the newest version of Spring, so I am puzzled by this error. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: which version of spring are you using ?

Comment: @jax I added `userDetailsService` bean to the question.

Comment: @SREEPRASAD GOVINDANKUTTY 2.5.5 as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because Spring Tools Suite comes with it's own spring libraries. So for the XML parsing and validation it does not use libraries on your project classpath.

Please see [STS-3679](https://jira.spring.io/browse/STS-3679)

Comment: Thank you, that explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Check your XML configuration files for both Spring and Spring security.
Do you have correct URLs in xsi:schemaLocation, like:

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
```

Comment: I believe so. I added the schemaLocation part to my question.